# Low image quality when scaled down using Glide on RecyclerView

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, android-glide

I have a `RecylerView` with grid layout and each list item has an image fed from the server. All images are sized 180x180px. I use Glide for this purpose.

Here is the snippet from `build.gradle`

```
implementation 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide: 4.11.0
kapt 'com.github.bumptech.glide:compiler:4.11.0'
```

And the layout xml

```
<RelativeLayout
   android:layout_width="wrap_content"
   android:layout_height="wrap_content"
   android:gravity="center">

      <CustomImageView
         android:id="@+id/fileIcon"
         android:layout_width="wrap_content"
         android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

And on the `RecyclerViewAdapter`, I use this to load from Glide, different scale type based on the condition below. For images fetched from the server, size scaled to 180x180dp and `centerCrop` is used

```
if(useLocalResource) {
   fileIcon.setScaleType("centerInside") 
   Glide.with(itemView).load(resId).into(fileIcon)
    
} else {
   //load from the server
   val iconSize = (itemView.context.resource.displayMetrics.density * 180).toInt()
   Glide.with(itemView).load(iconUrl).override(iconSize, iconSize)
         .listener(object : RequestListener<Drawable> {
                       override fun onLoadFailed(
                            e: GlideException?, model: Any?,
                            target: Target<Drawable>?, isFirstResource: Boolean
                   ): Boolean {
                         fileIcon.setImageDrawable(previewDrawable)
                         return true
                   }

                    override fun onResourceReady(resource: Drawable?, model: Any?, target: 
                         Target<Drawable>?, dataSource: DataSource?, isFirstResource: Boolean
                     ): Boolean = false
                }).centerCrop().into(fileIcon) 
}
```

And the Glide module is

```
@GlideModule
class LivedriveGlideModule : AppGlideModule() {
    override fun applyOptions(context: Context, builder: GlideBuilder) {
           builder.setDefaultRequestOptions(RequestOptions()
                  .diskCacheStrategy(DiskCacheStrategy.DATA)
                  .format(DecodeFormat.PREFER_ARGB_8888))
    }
}
```

The image quality is poor and blurry. Not sure if I miss any configuration. Tried couple of solutions I found online, like this one.

```
implementation ("com.github.bumptech.glide:okhttp3-integration:4.11.0"){
    exclude(group="glide-parent")
}
```

Used `dontTransform()` with no luck too. Any inputs would be highly appreciated

Comment: "All images are sized 180x180dp" -- image files, such as PNG and JPEG, are not measured in `dp`. Do you mean 180 x 180 pixels? If so, they are going to be "poor and blurry" on high-density screens, if you try putting them into `180dp` square `ImageView` widgets.

Comment: I convert 180dp into density equivalent pixel, please see the edit 'iconSize' variable. Or are we supposed to use SimpleTarget<Bitmap> class for scaled down images?